# How to identify coefficients with the binomialcoefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

i tried to identify the coefficients $\gamma n \nu \mu $ in

$$(a+b+c)^n = \sum_{\nu=0}^{n} \sum_{\mu = \nu}^{n} \gamma n \nu \mu ~a^\nu b^{\mu- \nu}c^{n- \mu}.$$

I used the Binomial Theorem, but didn't succeed, can you help me?

Binomial Theorem:
$$(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} a^{n-k}b^k$$

Comment: Use $(a+b+c)^n=(a+(b+c))^n$.

Comment: I understand, that its $$(a+b+c)^n = \sum_{\nu=0}^{n} a^{\nu} b^{-\nu} \sum_{\mu = \nu}^{n} \gamma n \nu \mu ~b^{\mu}c^{n- \mu}.$$ so the second term is $(b+c)^n$ except for $\gamma n \nu \mu $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
  (a+b+c)^n &= \sum_k\binom nka^k(b+c)^{n-k}
  \\ &= \sum_k\binom nka^k\sum_l\binom klb^lc^{n-k-l}
  \\ &= \sum_k\sum_l\binom nk\binom kla^kb^lc^{n-k-l}
  \\ &= \sum_{k+l+m=n}\binom nk\binom kla^kb^lc^m
  \\ &= \sum_{k+l+m=n}\binom n{k,l,m}a^kb^lc^m
\qquad\text{where $\binom n{k,l,m}\overset{\rm def}=\binom nk\binom kl=\frac{n!}{k!l!m!}.
$}
\end{align}
$$
Such products of binomial coefficients are called [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient). The coefficent $\binom n{k,l,m}$ counts permutations of the letters of the word aaa...bb...ccc... of length $n$ with $k$ letters 'a', with $l$ letters 'b', and with $m$ letters 'c'; for instance $\binom7{2,1,4}$ counts permutations of aabcccc. Such permutations (with repetitions) are the products you get when working out $(a+b+c)^n$, leaving monomials as they are obtained from applying the distributive law, *without* regrouping the same variables together.

Comment: i dont really get it, why ist this the solution?

Comment: What's your problem? It there any step that you have doubt about? Can you recognise the coefficients in the final polynomial (even though they are not designated by Greek letters)? To help you: the coefficient of $a^kb^lc^m$ is the product $\binom nk\binom kl$, which can be written $\frac{n!}{k!\,l!\,m!}$ and for which the notation $\binom n{k,l,m}$ is introduced. (The latter is defined only when $n=k+l+m$.)